# Tower of Hanoi Python: Use of local and global variables changes the output

Tags: python, python-3.x, towers-of-hanoi

So, I was working on my Tower of Hanoi algorithm in Python, with the 3 stacks being represented as lists. This is the code:

```
def move(stack, inter_stack, final_stack):
    disk=stack.pop()
    final_stack.append(disk)
    print(stack, inter_stack, final_stack)

def moveDisks(n,start,end,inter):
    if n==1:
        move(start, inter, end)
    else:
        moveDisks(n-1,start,inter,end)
        move(start, inter, end)
        moveDisks(n-1,inter,end,start)

n = input("Enter the # of blocks: ")
n = int(n)
start=[]
inter=[]
end=[]
for i in range(n):
   start=start+[n-i]
moveDisks(n,start,end,inter)
```

If I run this code with n = 3, the result Python gives me is the following:

```
[3, 2] [] [1]
[3] [1] [2]
[] [3] [2, 1]
[] [2, 1] [3]
[2] [3] [1]
[] [1] [3, 2]
[] [] [3, 2, 1]
```

In this output it is clearly seen that the stacks are out of order. However, if I substitute the line

```
print(stack, inter_stack, final_stack)
```

with

```
print(start, inter, end)
```

The code outputs the stacks in the correct order:

```
[3, 2] [] [1]
[3] [2] [1]
[3] [2, 1] []
[] [2, 1] [3]
[1] [2] [3]
[1] [] [3, 2]
[] [] [3, 2, 1]
```

Why is this happening, considering that both sets of variables carry the same values, the second way just using global variables?

Answer (score 1):

When you recurse you change the meanings of the stacks with these two calls:

```
moveDisks(n - 1, start, inter, end)
moveDisks(n - 1, inter, end, start)
```

Note the changing order.  Thus inside `move()`

```
print(stack, inter_stack, final_stack)
```

will be referring to different lists each time.

Comment: Then why print(start, inter, end) gives me a correct order? Since the meanings are changing, shouldn't that statement print in the wrong order as well? Or does it always take the original meanings of start, inter and end no matter the changes of meanings inside the recursion?

Comment: The thing to understand, that you are missing, is that **variables** are just names, and they are only valid in the appropriate context.  Since `start, inter ,end` are globals inside of `move`, their context is global, and the meaning does not change based on context. Thus you view them as *correct* in your prints.  But in `moveDisks` those sames names are locals, and thus change depending on how the method is called.